# How to use checkboxes and ServerPaging at Kendo UI?

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I have the following project. There you can click on the individual checkboxes and the ID is written (see Console).

Then I have tested the ServerPaging. This works in another project (there are no checkboxes). If I change the above project to ServerPaging, I can click on the checkbox, but it reloads the DataSource. What can I do here?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Grid with checkboxes</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.911/styles/kendo.bootstrap-v4.min.css" />

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.911/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/content/shared/js/console.js"></script>
  
</head>

<body>

  <style>

    html {
      font-size: 14px;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    label {
      float: left;
      line-height: 1;
    }

    [role='gridcell'] {
      box-shadow: none !important;
    }

    .checkColumnCenter {
      text-align: center;
      width: 20px;
    }
    
    .fieldlist {
      margin: 0 0 -1em;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .fieldlist li {
      list-style: none;
      padding-bottom: 1em;
    }

  </style>

  <div id="example">
    <div id="grid"></div>
  </div>
  <script>
    

  $(document).ready(function() {

    var MainArray = [];
    var subArray = [];
    var selectedItems = [];
    var pageNum;
    var initialLength = 0;
    var confirmedArray = [];
    
  var crudServiceBaseUrl = "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service",
        
    dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
      transport: {
        read: {
          url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Products",
          dataType: "jsonp"
        },
        update: {
          url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products/update",
          dataType: "jsonp"
        },
        parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
          if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
            return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
          }
          return kendo.data.transports["odata"].parameterMap(options, operation);
        }
      },
      pageSize: 10,
      type: "odata",
      batch: true,
      serverPaging: false,
      serverSorting: false,
      /*serverPaging: true,
      serverFiltering: true,
      serverSorting: true,
      batch: true,*/
      schema: {
        model: {
          id: "ProductID",
          fields: {
            ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
            ProductName: { validation: { required: true } },
            UnitPrice: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1 } },
            Discontinued: { type: "boolean" },
            UnitsInStock: { type: "number", validation: { min: 0, required: true } }
          }
        },
        data: function (response) {
          return response.d ? response.d.results: response;
        }
      }
    });


    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
      dataSource: dataSource,
      height: 350,
      navigatable: true,
      pageable: true,
      sortable: true,
      persistSelection: true,
      filterable: {
        extra: false,
        mode: 'row',
        operators: {
          string: {
            contains: "Contains",
            startswith: "Starts with",
            eq: "Equal",
            neq: "Not equal"
          }
        },
        messages: {
          isTrue: "checked",
          isFalse: "selectable"
        }
      },
      resizable: true,
      columns: [{
          field: "Discontinued",
          width: 150,
          template: "<input type='checkbox' onclick='checkOne()' data-bind='checked:Discontinued' />",
          headerTemplate: "<input id='checkAll' type='checkbox' onclick='checkAll(this)'/><span id='checkAllPtext'></span>",
          attributes: {
            "class": "checkColumnCenter",
            style: "color:\\#0c0"
          }
        },
        {
          field: "ProductName",
          title: "Product",
          width: 150
        },
        {
          field: "UnitPrice",
          title: "Unit",
          width: 120
        },
        {
          field: "UnitsInStock",
          title: "Costplace",
          width: 120
        },
      ],
      dataBound: function(e) {
        
        if(this.dataSource.filter()){
              $('#checkAll').show(); 
              $('#checkAllPtext').show().html("All");
            } else {
              $('#checkAll').hide();
              $('#checkAllPtext').hide();
            }
        
        selectedItems = [];
        var selectedItemsPage = [];

        e.sender.items().each(function() {
          var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem(this);
          kendo.bind(this, dataItem);

          if (dataItem.Discontinued) {
            var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
            var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this);
            selectedItemsPage.push(dataItem);
            $(this).addClass("k-state-selected");
          }

        });

        if (pageNum == e.sender.dataSource._page) {
          // kendoConsole.log('initialLength', initialLength)
          if (initialLength !== 0) {
            // MainArray.splice(-initialLength);
            // kendoConsole.log('subArray', MainArray.indexOf(subArray[0]))
            subArray.forEach(function(item, i) {
              MainArray.splice(MainArray.indexOf(item), 1);
            });
          }
          if (selectedItemsPage.length > 0) {
            selectedItems = selectedItemsPage;
          }
          subArray = selectedItemsPage;
          initialLength = selectedItems.length;
        } else {
          selectedItemsPage.forEach(function(item) {
            if (MainArray.indexOf(item) > -1) {
              MainArray.splice(MainArray.indexOf(item), 1);
            }
          });
          pageNum = e.sender.dataSource._page;
          if (selectedItemsPage.length > 0) {
            selectedItems = selectedItemsPage;
          }
          subArray = selectedItemsPage;
          initialLength = selectedItems.length;
        }

        MainArray = MainArray.concat(selectedItems);
        // kendoConsole.log(MainArray);
        $("#checkAll")[0].checked = e.sender.items().find(":checked").length == e.sender.dataSource.view().length;
      }
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
      getMarked();
    }, 500);

    getMarked = function() {
      dataSource.fetch(function() {
        confirmedArray = dataSource._data.filter(function(item) {
          return item.Discontinued;
        })
        var confirmedIDs = confirmedArray.map(function(item) {
          return item.ProductID;
        });
        kendoConsole.log(JSON.stringify("Selected ID's: " + confirmedIDs));
      })
    }
    // setTimeout(function () {
    //     getMarked();
    // }, 200);
  });

    var getMarked;
    function checkOne() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        getMarked();
      }, 100);
    }

    function checkAll(input) {
      var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
      var items = grid.items();
      items.each(function() {
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this);
        if (dataItem.Discontinued != input.checked) {
          dataItem.Discontinued = input.checked;
          dataItem.dirty = true;
        }
      })
      grid.dataSource.sync();
      setTimeout(function() {
        getMarked();
      }, 100);
    }
  </script>
  
        <div class="box wide">
        <h4>Console log</h4>
        <div class="console"></div>
    </div>
    <style>
        .console div {
            height: 6em;
        }
    </style>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I helped it with a simple check `array.length > 0`

```html
        getMarked = function() {
          if (array.length > 0) {
            // foo nothing 
          }
          dataSource.fetch(function() {
            confirmedArray = dataSource._data.filter(function(item) {
              return item.Discontinued;
            })
            var confirmedIDs = confirmedArray.map(function(item) {
              return item.ProductID;
            });
          })
        }
```

The problem was that the grid was reloaded every time after an action. Since the changes in the grid have not been saved yet, he has discarded the changes each time. Is a good workaround for me.